# "falling due" vs "due"

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

What's the definition of **falling due** and how did its sense materialise? Please compare it against "due"? I'm mindful that it's an accounting/business term: here are [its matches on Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Falling+due%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22Falling+due%22&safe=off&start=0&tbm=bks).

I'm not after the etymology of each word, but rather how **falling + due** (ostensibly) denotes [maturity](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/falling+due)?

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/business-english/amount-falling-due-after-one-year?q=%22falling+due%22 seems to connote that **falling due** = **due**?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's simply a natural consequence of one of the meanings of "to fall", that being to occur at a specific time ([sense 16 here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fall)).  In a similar way to "Christmas Day falls on a Wednesday this year" the day on which something is scheduled to happen is the day on which it "falls due".